# Can I re-enable token mint after disabling it?

Tags: blockchain, solana

If I run

`spl-token authorize tokenAddress mint --disable`

Will I ever be able to enable back the mint?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: haha, sorry but this is the funniest question I've read all day ;) take my upvote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once disabled, you cannot reenable minting.

This is to avoid projects from re-enabling minting and inflating the supply if the mint is disabled.